# filtering an array of objects based on another array returning new array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, es6-promise

I have an array of object, which we can call arrayOne and want to check with arrayTwo if it contain any string that match with ArrayOne, and it will return new array with matching array. What is the best approach I can do using ES6 ?

Example :

```
ArrayOne =    [  
       {  
          "sessionId":1,
          "name":"session name 1",
          "types":[  
             "type1",
             "type 2"
          ],
          "tracks":[  
             "track1",
             "track 2"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "sessionId":2,
          "name":"session name 2",
          "types":[  
             "track 3",
             "type 2"
          ],
          "tracks":[  
             "track 3",
             "track 2"
          ]
       }
    ]


arrayTwo = ["track 3"] // or it can be ["track&3", "Type 2"] which it will return both array
```

return

```
newArray =  [ {  
      "sessionId":2,
      "name":"session name 2",
      "types":[  
         "track 3",
         "type 2"
      ],
      "tracks":[  
         "track 3",
         "track 2"
      ]
   }]
```

I tried the following :

```
arrayOne.filter((obj) => {
                Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
                    if (obj[key].toString().indexOf(arrayTwo) !== -1) {
                        this.setState({
                            newArray: [obj]
                        })
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the tracks array, you could do something like this:

```
ArrayOne.filter((obj) => arrayTwo.some(x => obj.tracks.includes(x)));
```

.some() returns true if arrayTwo contains some element x such that obj.tracks has a matching element.

Comment: yeah Agree this will work for only tracks, but the element could be in any obj not only tracks. Thanks @erik

Comment: In that case, you might want to look into a recursive solution.  Recursion is the only way I know of to exhaustively check each element of an object, as well as all deeply nested objects and arrays within it.  However, if each object you're checking is always going to have the same structure, you might get better performance by simply performing multiple checks, ie (obj.tracks.includes(x) || obj.types.includes(x))

Comment: I end up doing this, performance wise is better Thanks @erik.